# save the path of camera image into SQLite table and retrieve it

Tags: android, android-camera

I have posted this problem yesterday..but unfortunately, no one has given me the solution and I still dont know where my mistake is.

I just want to save the path of an image taken by the camera into a SQLite table. And afetr that I want ot retrieve this path from the database and display the picture.

Code:

```
public void takePic() {
    String fileName = "temp.jpg";  
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);  
    mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);  

    cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, Camera_requestCode);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == Camera_requestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA}; 
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(mCapturedImageURI, projection, null, null, null); 
        int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA); 
        cursor.moveToFirst(); 
        String capturedImageFilePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);

        insertPath(capturedImageFilePath);
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    }
};
```

Logcat:

```
03-02 13:20:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(378): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

03-02 13:20:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(378): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.android.SaveCameraPictureDemo/com.android.SaveCameraPictureDemo.SaveCameraPictureDemoActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.android.SaveCameraPictureDemo/com.android.SaveCameraPictureDemo.SaveCameraPictureDemoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-02 13:20:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2120)
03-02 13:20:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
03-02 13:20:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1668)
03-02 13:20:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2832)
03-02 13:20:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-02 13:20:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
03-02 13:20:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-02 13:20:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-02 13:20:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-02 13:20:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 13:20:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-02 13:20:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-02 13:20:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-02 13:20:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-02 13:20:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(378): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.android.SaveCameraPictureDemo/com.android.SaveCameraPictureDemo.SaveCameraPictureDemoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-02 13:20:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
03-02 13:20:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2107)
03-02 13:20:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  ... 13 more
03-02 13:20:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(378): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-02 13:20:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContentResolver.java:743)
03-02 13:20:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:256)
03-02 13:20:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.Activity.managedQuery(Activity.java:1550)
03-02 13:20:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at com.android.SaveCameraPictureDemo.SaveCameraPictureDemoActivity.onActivityResult(SaveCameraPictureDemoActivity.java:67)
03-02 13:20:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
03-02 13:20:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2528)
03-02 13:20:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  ... 14 more
03-02 13:36:55.168: E/AndroidRuntime(434): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 13:36:55.168: E/AndroidRuntime(434): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.android.SaveCameraPictureDemo/com.android.SaveCameraPictureDemo.SaveCameraPictureDemoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-02 13:36:55.168: E/AndroidRuntime(434):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
03-02 13:36:55.168: E/AndroidRuntime(434):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2574)
03-02 13:36:55.168: E/AndroidRuntime(434):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-02 13:36:55.168: E/AndroidRuntime(434):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:961)
03-02 13:36:55.168: E/AndroidRuntime(434):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-02 13:36:55.168: E/AndroidRuntime(434):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-02 13:36:55.168: E/AndroidRuntime(434):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-02 13:36:55.168: E/AndroidRuntime(434):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 13:36:55.168: E/AndroidRuntime(434):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-02 13:36:55.168: E/AndroidRuntime(434):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-02 13:36:55.168: E/AndroidRuntime(434):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-02 13:36:55.168: E/AndroidRuntime(434):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-02 13:36:55.168: E/AndroidRuntime(434): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-02 13:36:55.168: E/AndroidRuntime(434):  at com.android.SaveCameraPictureDemo.SaveCameraPictureDemoActivity.onActivityResult(SaveCameraPictureDemoActivity.java:73)
03-02 13:36:55.168: E/AndroidRuntime(434):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
03-02 13:36:55.168: E/AndroidRuntime(434):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2528)
03-02 13:36:55.168: E/AndroidRuntime(434):  ... 11 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code,

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == Camera_requestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

       if(data != null)
       {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA}; 
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(mCapturedImageURI, projection, null, null, null); 
        int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA); 
        cursor.moveToFirst(); 
        String capturedImageFilePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);

        insertPath(capturedImageFilePath);
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
      }
     else
     {
       Log.e("OnActivityResult()", "data is null");
     }
    }
};
```

Comment: now it does not crash..but can u tell me what is log.e and how can I retrive the path of the picture to display it elsewhere

Comment: Your intent data is null, so you got forceclose, It means you have a problem in your camera activity to back result picture data.